# Android Navigation Bar covering viewpager content

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigationbar

I can't stop the Systems Navigation Bar from covering up my content!

[image]

I am scrolled to the very bottom of the recyclerview but its getting hidden behind the navigation bar. Here is my XML layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:fab_colorNormal="@color/accent"
    app:fab_colorPressed="@color/accent_dark" />
```

Here is the fragments layout which you are seeing in the picture.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="8dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Ive tried adding android:fitsSystemWindows="true" into every piece of layout I could but that did not work. Other threads mention adding margin calculated from the bar, but that doesn't seem like the proper solution. I grabbed this layout directly from Google's CheesSquare app demo'ing the appbarlayout, and that one looks like its working fine.

Comment: No, the activity is not full screen. Its a standard activity, no special flags or anything.

Comment: Add suitable margin_bottom to your RecyclerView or root view. This should fix your issue.

Comment: Thats a good fix, but i'm trying to get to the root of the problem. This doesn't seem to be normal behavior.

Comment: I have the exact problem too :(

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede the latest version of the support library seemed to have fixed it for me. I do sometimes get the issue though using an appbarlayout its somewhat random though.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I think i FINALLY figured it out. I was setting my toolbar from the fragment inside onViewCreated(); I moved this into onCreateView() and viola it works now,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Figured it out. In my particular situation each of my fragments manage their own toolbar instance. I was calling setSupportActionBar() in the onViewCreated() method on my fragments. Moving this functionality into onCreateView() solved it.

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_account, container, false);
        setupToolbar((Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        return view;
    }

    private void setupToolbar(Toolbar toolbar) {
        toolbarController.registerToolbar(toolbar);
        toolbarController.setActivityTitle("My Account");
    }
```

(registerToolbar() calls setSupportActionBar() inside the hosting activity).

Hope this helps everyone!

Comment: What is toolbarController here?

Comment: oh god, that's really not trivial

Answer (score 1):

Viewpager's fragment root view has to be `RecyclerView` or `NestedScrollView`. `FrameLayout` doesn't support scrolling behavior of `CoordinatorLayout` and this is why it doesn't work well.

How you can fix the viewpager's fragment layout: don't wrap `RecyclerView` inside `FrameLayout`. Instead declare `RecyclerView` at the root. You also can set `padding="8dp"` on `RecyclerView`, just use `android:clipToPadding="false"`.

Comment: I was using Srcollview inside CoordinatorLayout, facing similar issue, able to fix that

Answer (score 1):

Wrap ViewPager into ConstraintLayout then, set to your viewpager:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

that should work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is using of `AppBarLayout`. The `CoordinatorLayout` was introduced as powerful `FrameLayout` which brings nice animations based on defined `Behaviors`. If we want to add some kind of `scroll` animation, like `collapsing toolbar`, etc. then we have to wrap our `Toolbar` with `AppBarLayout`, but when we want to place a static content inside `CoordinatorLayout`, such as `ViewPager` in your case, then we don't need to use `AppBarLayout` at all:

*activity_main.xml:*

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.mydemoci.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

*content_main.xml:*

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#A1D490"

    // Remember CoordinatorLayout is a kind of FrameLayout,
    // so we have to provide top margin to make Toolbar visible
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"

    tools:context="com.mydemoci.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don't think you should be adding a marginTop at all. For a more flexible solution - handles app bar layouts with tabs or collapsingtoolbarlayouts, you should just wrap your toolbar in an appbarlayout and use app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

Answer (score 0):

Go to style.xml and remove these two items, or set their "true" values to "false".

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

In my case the problem was solved by removing these two theme styles values.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding margin bottom to `View Pager` fix it for me.

Here is the code in my activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/main_viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"/>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Answer (score -4):

try to replace your gradle dependency

```
com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.+
```

with

```
com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0
```

or

```
com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+
```

(not sure this is the right notation)